# How to add a span element to an i18n localized label in Rails 3.2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I would like to add a `span` element to my **i18n** localized label in Rails 3.2.3.

This is what I've got:

```
<%= f.label :address, "<span class=\"optional\">optional</span>".html_safe %>
```

However, in the output it produces:

```
<label for="person_address">
  <span class="optional">optional</span>
</label>
```

What I need is this:

```
<label for="person_address">
  Address <span class="optional">optional</span>
</label>
```

Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the block form and translate the attribute name "manually" :

```
<%= f.label :address do %>
  <%= f.object.class.human_attribute_name :address %>
  <span class="optional">optional</span>
<% end %>
```

note

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter in the 'label' helper will be the text of the label.  If you did this:

```
<%= f.label :address, "Address <span class=\"optional\">optional</span>".html_safe %>
```

It would show correctly, I think.

You an also add html to the yml file and use .html_safe on the yml item explicitly it would also work.

```
<%= f.label :address, t('path.to.label').html_safe %>
```

I'd also be tempted to try something with javascript and css - to class the field and add something via jquery or with a css :after to the label.